# Passing HttpPostedFileBase to Controller

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to pass an audio blob recorded in my view to my Controller. Following is what I have done so far.

// Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Record(TestAudio data)
{
    return View();
}
```

and TestAudio Data is as follows

```
public class TestAudio
{
    public TestAudio()
    {
        UserDetails = new User();

    }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Sample;
    public User UserDetails;
}

public class User
{
    string UserName;
}
```

Jquery submit is as follows

```
$('#send').click(function () {
        var answer = {
            sample: recorded,  // Where recorded is a variable containing my blob
            userdetails : null
        }

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data", answer);
        debugger;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../home/record',
            data: data,
            //contentType: 'application/my-binary-type', // set to whatever you like
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
    });
    });
```

However, am getting data as null in my controller. If i was to use a HttpPostedFileBase alone as the Controller parameter, it works. But when am using a complex parameter such as TestAudio, it fails.

Could someone guide me ?

Comment: I could find an answer myself. Thought will share it here, in case someone else needs

 var data = new FormData();
            data.append("sample", blob);
            data.append("userdetails", userdetails);

Basically ended giving it as separate form data elments

Answer (score 0):

I could find an answer myself. Thought will share it here, in case someone else needs

```
var data = new FormData(); 
data.append("sample", blob); 
data.append("userdetails", userdetails);
```

Basically ended giving it as separate form data elements. That kind of did the trick.